# How to use RANK() SQl Function?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a **Marks** table where i have a column **marks_score** and i want to add a Rank column using select query using **Order BY Marks_score Desc**.

I dont know how to use RANK() SQL Function

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Did you look at [`RANK`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) in the documentation?

Comment: why is this question tagged c# and asp.net, are you asking for someone to write the code to talk to SQL as well for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

**RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TOTAL_CNT DESC DESC) AS Rank**

```
 select t1.*,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t1.Marks_score DESC) AS Rank  from Marks as t1
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT  *,RANK() OVER (order by marks_score  desc) as rnk
FROM    Marks
```

You can find more examples [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/10/09/sql-server-2005-sample-example-of-ranking-functions-row_number-rank-dense_rank-ntile/)

Same way You can use ROW_NUMBER(), DESNSE_RANK() functions..

Please read [this](http://thehobt.blogspot.in/2009/02/rownumber-rank-and-denserank.html) article to find the difference between them